# window.open not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, explorer

Try to get this running, runs in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and whatever but IE7 does not open a popup bar, in the console I just get "invalid argument"

It is in the onclick of an image

```
<img style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;" onclick='window.open("http://www.test.com", "Image Gallery", "width=850,height=1000,resizable=no,menubar=no");' src="thumb.jpg" width="64" height="64"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

target is not allowed to have spaces.

```
<img style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;" onclick='window.open("http://www.test.com", "Image_Gallery", "width=850,height=1000,resizable=no,menubar=no");' src="thumb.jpg" width="64" height="64"/>
```

Comment: Uh, how triviasl! Many thanks. I think i had this f** a few years ago, too